# Envers, Liquibase and Hibernate

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, liquibase, nhibernate-envers

i looking for a way for create (with DDL = none in hibernate) the schema for the audit tables on the fly.

At the moment i use liquibase for create the schema of my tables. The configuration is with hibernate (spring boot application) with a DB2 database. At the moment i have errors with the insert statement for envers tables (because no tables are exist):

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [insert into revinfo (rev, revtstmp) values (default, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
```

I have read in Hibernate 4 with the liquibase Hibernate plugin it is possible to create the tables without any special configuration with the exception of the tag `<referenceUrl>`
in the pom.xml

here my configuration:

**pom.xml**

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml</changeLogFile>
                <diffChangeLogFile>target/${maven.build.timestamp}_liquibase_changelog.xml</diffChangeLogFile>
                <driver>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</driver>
                <url>jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/test</url>
                <username>${db.username}</username>
                <password>test</password>
                <referenceUrl>hibernate:spring:de.test.tool.domain?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</referenceUrl>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <logging>debug</logging>
                <propertyFileWillOverride>false</propertyFileWillOverride>
                <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                <contexts>${liquibase.contexts}</contexts>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                    <version>3.18.2-GA</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate4</artifactId>
                    <version>${liquibase-hibernate4.version}</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

**Entitybean**

```
package de.test.tool.domain;

import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

    /**
     * Test-Entitaet.
     */
    @Entity
    @Audited
    @Table(name="CALCULATEVALUE")
    @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
    public class CalculateValue {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;

        @Column(nullable = false, name="OWN_VALUE")
        private int ownValue = 0;

        @Column(nullable = false, name="CALCULATION_DATE_LONG")
        private long calculationDateLong = 0;

        public int getOwnValue() {
            return ownValue;
        }

        public void setOwnValue(int ownValue) {
            this.ownValue = ownValue;
        }


        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public long getCalculationDateLong() {
            return calculationDateLong;
        }

        public void setCalculationDateLong(long calculationDateLong) {
            this.calculationDateLong = calculationDateLong;
        }
```

**application.properties**

```
# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager).

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql=true


# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update, none): with "update" the database
# schema will be automatically updated accordingly to java entities found in
# the project
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false

# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================

# Set here configurations for the database connection

# Connection url for the database "netgloo_blog"

spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:localhost:50000/test
# password
spring.datasource.password=test

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT values(1)
```